# How do I set a due date that replicates every xx days?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

Suppose I want to remember a due date every month on a Trello board. Can I add on a card a date that replicates every month, say every 30 days?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no automatic changes on cards (except color changes as the due date arrives and passes).

When we use a monthly board for tasks and repeating mini-projects we have team members manually change the dates as they complete the card.  Usually the day of the month changed so we kept it to things like "last Friday of the month", "Second Tuesday" etc.

Once everyone gets used to it, I think it works better.  It's easy to overlook something that automatically changes without knowing if the card is complete.

Answer (score 1):

As told by Kevan, it is not possible within the card itself.
However, to avoid scenario when busy humans forget manually checking long-term cards, automate tasks for them:

Use an IFTT/Zapier automation service + Gmail Calendar (or any calendar of your preference) to regularly:

- create new cards on a board with templates like "Review project X in 3 days", or
- periodically send templated emails to comments on specifically targeted cards, which will trigger notifications to all cards members at the date you need.